# File name too long error with command 'stat'

Tags: find, xargs, stat

I retrieve a booklist after seaching the python books in home directory using this command on OSX:

```
    find ~ -type f -iregex '.*python.*\.pdf'
```

the booklist

```
    ...
    .../Computing/Python/Beginning_Python.pdf
    .../Python/Core.Python.Applications.Programming.3rd.Edition.pdf
    .../Python/Packt.Mastering.Python.2016.4.pdf
    ...
```

I intend to check their status with command `xargs` and `stat`

```
    $ find ~ -type f -iregex '.*python.*\.pdf' | xargs stat -x
    # get error
    xargs: unterminated quote
```

Tried alternatively with option `-0`

```
    find ~ -type f -iregex '.*python.*\.pdf' | xargs -0 stat -x 
    # get error
    : stat: File name too long
```

How to resolve such a problem?

Comment: this is on OSX, I assume? (`stat -x`)

Comment: Note that `-iregex '.*python.*\.pdf'` will match on `/path/to/python/whatever/foo.pdf`. If you want to match on files whose **name** (as opposed to full path) contains `python` and ends in `.pdf`, use `-iname '*python*.pdf'` or `-iregexp '.*python[^/]*\.pdf'`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`-0` to xargs doesn't make much sense if you don't also change the input to be 0-separated. Try `find ~ -type f -iregex '.*python.*\.pdf' -print0 | xargs -0 stat -x`

Comment: Some `xargs` implementations also have a `-r` option to not run the command if the input is empty (on FreeBSD, it's implicit).